# Converting an angle into a different value

Tags: trigonometry, ratio

I hope i can ask this question. Its cleary related to some field of math, where as i dont know how its called..In fact, i cant even describe the problems in terms that a professional would understand in a few words (topic).

[picture example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgHyH.jpg)

The green and red dot represent a starship each.

Based upon the angle between both starships (they are shooting each) other, i want to calculate a a chance to hit that specific target from that angle.

Starships have fixed hit chances for the 4 major locations, front/aft/port/board or 0/180/90/270 respectivly.
However, if the firing angle is between those arcs, i want to calculate a mixed hitchances based on the two nearest profile values.

In the example below, a angle of 45 degree would certainly result in 77.5% (70 + 85/2). However, for 44 or 46 degree im already unsure.

However, for any hit angle between 0 and 90, excluding 45, i dont know i would calculate the...average ? for that specific angle.
Can anyone advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use something that mathematicians call "linear interpolation". It's really just a more general version of the technique you used to get a value for 45 degrees.

Suppose you know the probabilities $P_A$ and $P_B$ for two angles $A$ and $B$. Now we want to calculate the probability $P_C$ for some other angle $C$, where $A \le C \le B$.

The linear interpolation formula is:
$$
P_C = \frac{(B-C)P_A + (C-A)P_B  }{B - A}
$$
Note that:

- When $C=A$, the formula gives $P_A$
- When $C=B$, the formula gives $P_B$
- When $C$ is between $A$ and $B$, you get a result that's between $P_A$ and $P_B$
- If $C = \tfrac12(A+B)$, then $P_C = \tfrac12(P_A+P_B)$

**Example 1:**
 Suppose $A = 0$ and $B=90$, and the corresponding probabilities are $P_A = 70$ and $P_B = 85$. If $C=45$, then
$$
P_C = \frac{(90-45)*(70) + (45-0)*(85) }{90 - 0} = 77.5
$$ 
**Example 2:**
 Suppose $A = 0$ and $B=90$, and the corresponding probabilities are $P_A = 70$ and $P_B = 85$. If $C=30$, then
$$
P_C = \frac{(90-30)*(70) + (30-0)*(85) }{90 - 0} = 75
$$

Comment: Yep. Another way to think of it is if you're at 22.5 degrees, which is 25% of the way from angle 0 to angle 90, then your probability should be 25% of the way from 70 to 85. $70+(.25)15$

Comment: Well, it worked. Thanks !